# Searching numpy array of objects by condition

Tags: python, numpy

Let's say we have a numpy array like this:

`array([{'k': 1}, {'k': 2}, {'k': 3}])`

Is is possible to filter filter out only the elements that fulfill a certain condition? For example return only the dictionaries whose keys are > 1. Something like filter() function with lambda. I was looking into numpy.where() but I can't figure out the proper syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing special related to numpy here, just

```
a = [{'k': 1}, {'k': 2}, {'k': 3}]
b = list(filter(lambda dic: dic['k'] > 1, a))
```

would work.

```
a = numpy.array([{'k': 1}, {'k': 2}, {'k': 3}])
b = numpy.array(list( filter(lambda dic: dic['k'] > 1, a) ) )
```

should work just as well.

Point is that you don't get any advantages of numpy if your array is onedimensional and you remove elements – Python's `list` is perfectly capable of that.

(assuming Python3, here, by the way.)

Comment: Thanks, that's what I thought. I will try to use different data structure instead of dict then.

Comment: If you know that your array elements always going to have a fixed set of keys, why not simply a 2d array?

Comment: That's not exactly the real life case I have but yeah, I will use a multidimensional arrays, thanks!